# why the linux source repo modified automatically in macOS 12.5

Tags: git

I am using this command to clone the linux repo in macOS 12.5:

```
git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

but when I using git status to show the repo info, the repo have some modified files:

```
➜  linux git:(master) ✗ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
    modified:   include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h
    modified:   include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_MARK.h
    modified:   include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h
    modified:   include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h
    modified:   include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h
    modified:   include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_TTL.h
    modified:   include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h
    modified:   net/netfilter/xt_DSCP.c
    modified:   net/netfilter/xt_HL.c
    modified:   net/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.c
    modified:   net/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.c
    modified:   tools/memory-model/litmus-tests/Z6.0+pooncelock+poonceLock+pombonce.litmus

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I did not modified any files of this repo, why the git status show modified files? This is part of the git diff show:

```
diff --git a/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h b/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
index 36cc956ead1a..41b578ccd03b 100644
--- a/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
+++ b/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
@@ -1,7 +1,37 @@
-/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 WITH Linux-syscall-note */
-#ifndef _XT_CONNMARK_H_target
-#define _XT_CONNMARK_H_target
+/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0+ WITH Linux-syscall-note */
+/* Copyright (C) 2002,2004 MARA Systems AB <https://www.marasystems.com>
+ * by Henrik Nordstrom <hno@marasystems.com>
+ */

-#include <linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h>
+#ifndef _XT_CONNMARK_H
+#define _XT_CONNMARK_H

-#endif /*_XT_CONNMARK_H_target*/
+#include <linux/types.h>
+
+enum {
+       XT_CONNMARK_SET = 0,
+       XT_CONNMARK_SAVE,
+       XT_CONNMARK_RESTORE
:
diff --git a/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h b/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
index 36cc956ead1a..41b578ccd03b 100644
--- a/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
+++ b/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
@@ -1,7 +1,37 @@
-/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 WITH Linux-syscall-note */
-#ifndef _XT_CONNMARK_H_target
-#define _XT_CONNMARK_H_target
+/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0+ WITH Linux-syscall-note */
+/* Copyright (C) 2002,2004 MARA Systems AB <https://www.marasystems.com>
+ * by Henrik Nordstrom <hno@marasystems.com>
```

when I using this command, shows error like this:

```
➜  linux git:(master) ✗ git checkout . --
fatal: invalid reference: .
```

Comment: What does `git diff` show?

Comment: This is _bizarre_, I am experiencing the same thing with the same netfilter files. `git reset --hard origin/master` doesn't clean them, `git restore .` doesn't revert them, never opened in an IDE, fresh clone... The first line of the diff changing `GPL-2.0` to `GPL-2.0+` seems like a potential hint, but I can't figure out why

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724849/differently-cased-files-in-kernel

Answer (score 3):

After experiencing it myself, I found the answer! It seems like the issue is that the repository can't be checked out on non case-sensitive filesystems. You can create a separate partition with case sensitivity, or maybe in a docker container.

Source: https://groups.google.com/g/git-users/c/FwG2UefGmeo

Comment: On macOS, I would suggest creating a case-sensitive disk image using the "Disk Utility" application.