# Differently Cased Files in Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

Cloning The Kernel currently (094226ad94f4) yeilds these conflicts on case-insensitive filesystems.

```
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_dscp.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_MARK.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ecn.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_TTL.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ttl.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h'
  'include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h'
  'net/netfilter/xt_DSCP.c'
  'net/netfilter/xt_dscp.c'
  'net/netfilter/xt_HL.c'
  'net/netfilter/xt_hl.c'
  'net/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.c'
  'net/netfilter/xt_rateest.c'
  'net/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.c'
  'net/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.c'
  'tools/memory-model/litmus-tests/Z6.0+pooncelock+poonceLock+pombonce.litmus'
  'tools/memory-model/litmus-tests/Z6.0+pooncelock+pooncelock+pombonce.litmus'
```

Could anyone explain to me *why* we seem to have two copies of each of these header files with slightly different names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Linux filesystems are case sensitive, so it isn’t expected to see case-insensitivity for Linux kernel source.

Each of these are similar, but not identical code.

For example, these two are different things for similar concepts. You choose between with kernel config options.

The match version is in `xt_hl.c`:

```
IP tables module for matching the value of the TTL
Hop Limit matching module

config NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HL
tristate '"hl" hoplimit/TTL match support'
depends on NETFILTER_ADVANCED
help
HL matching allows you to match packets based on the hoplimit
in the IPv6 header, or the time-to-live field in the IPv4
header of the packet.
```

Match allows one to write iptables rules that look for a given hoplimit.

The target version is in `xt_HL.c`:

```
TTL modification target for IP tables
Hop Limit modification target for ip6tables

config NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_HL
tristate '"HL" hoplimit target support'
depends on IP_NF_MANGLE || IP6_NF_MANGLE
depends on NETFILTER_ADVANCED
help
This option adds the "HL" (for IPv6) and "TTL" (for IPv4)
targets, which enable the user to change the
hoplimit/time-to-live value of the IP header.

While it is safe to decrement the hoplimit/TTL value, the
modules also allow to increment and set the hoplimit value of
the header to arbitrary values. This is EXTREMELY DANGEROUS
since you can easily create immortal packets that loop
forever on the network.
```

Target adds support to write iptables rules that modify the hoplimit on packets.

The code is similar by virtue of both dealing with ip tables and hoplimits.

Comment: If they're doing different things, that then begs the question why you'd call them the same thing differentiated only by casing

Comment: @ScottishTapWater they are similar, deal with concepts in different ways, or otherwise would be confusing if they had very different filenames. Or so I’d wager the thinking goes…

Comment: Fair enough, I'd imagine suffixing it with a discriminator would make more sense though... What happens if a third option arises?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater a suffix could have worked, *e.g.* `xt_hl_target.c` and `xt_hl_match.c` (assuming there isn’t some other reason for the file names). But the files in `uapi` are part of the kernel’s API and it is therefore unlikely that they will be changed; doing so would break compilation of programs relying on those headers.

Comment: Makes sense I suppose, an odd decision made in the past that we're sort of stuck with now I guess